# Using a clickable item to set a report variable in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with some variables.  I want to be able to set up a clickable report item that would call some custom code to change the report variable.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this under action tab of the report item properties, select "Go to report", specify the same report you are working on, and add your parameters below, changing the ones you want to change.
[image]

Comment: I was looking more for a way to change the "global" variables one can set up through ReportProperties->Variables, but this may do what I want as well.